# Перезапуск цикла через n секунду

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Есть приложение, реализующее обработку изменяющегося файла.
На форме есть кнопки "Старт" и "Стоп" меняющие значение переменной active.
Есть функция обработки данных.
Вопрос: как можно реализовать вызов этой функции каждые n секунд, пока переменная active!=0, наименее замороченным и понятным для новичка способом
**Qt5, c++**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать класс [QTimer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html), например так:

```
 void HandleDataFunction(); // функция для обработки данных

 //...

 auto timer = new QTimer(parent);
 timer->setInterval(1000 * n);
 QObject::connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, &HandleDataFunction);
 QObject::connect(ButtonStart, &QPushButton::clicked, timer, &QTimer::start);
 QObject::connect(ButtonStop , &QPushButton::clicked, timer, &QTimer::stop );
```